# How to query against multiple databases on the same server

Tags: mysql, sql, database, dynamic

I am not sure if this has been answered before but what I found i am not sure how to make work for me but here is my problem.

I have a database used to keep track of phones for multiple clients.  What needs to be done is have a query that can be ran that will run against multiple databases on the same server.  each database uses the same table name that I am looking at but the names are slightly different.  I came up with this..

`` INSERT INTO `export db`.exportinfo2
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM `export db'.tentantnames).users 
WHERE name = 'Caller ID:emergency' AND value > 0 ``

What suppose to happen is from a table that has all the database names is is to got to each database and go into the table labeled users and run a where clause on the data then export results to a different database table
I know the code needs to be dynamic but I am not sure how to make it dynamic and function.  The table that has all the names for the databases is automatically created every few days..  I am not sure what else needs to be said without sounding like i repeat myself but i just need help making a dynamic query that uses a table premade as database names and run a where statement on the same named table in each database which have their name stored in a different table.

Comment: Start by reading about [Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html). You will need to generate a dynamic [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) statement. [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) will also be usefull.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Synonyms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15). It can be used to fulfill your purpose